# Kiosk application in Android

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

I'm developing a Kiosk application. I have used the following intent filter to make it as Home app.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

When I reboot, I could still see that my app is up and running, but after a few seconds it's getting force closed and a dialog is shown to select launcher. I'm not getting any log information. I have seen the SureLock app which pretty much does this and on reboot this app is working fine. How could I do that on reboot?